# PHP not including file

Tags: php, .htaccess, require

I'm calling for a file with require in PHP, but it will not load.

The file is being redirected with htaccess, if that may have anything to do with it.

```
include '/assets/header.php';
require '/assets/adminPanel.php'; //file that will not load
```

Top of adminPanel.php:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$Hero_ = new Hero_;
$onMain = $Hero_->hero_checkMain($id);
$onSub = $Hero_->hero_checkSub($id, $article['cat']);

if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
if($user_i['rank'] > 0) {
?>
```

I've tried deleting the PHP at the top of that file with no luck, and the rest of the initial page will not load on account of require not being able to fetch the file.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you have "?>" before closing ifs ?

Comment: @mitch possibly some `html` or something he did not include.

Comment: And why is it related to htaccess?

Comment: @Starkeen The file is a htaccess redirect, so I have to give the absolute URL of any files included. I thought that may have something to do with adminPanel.php not being included. 

However, it was solved by using realpath as mentioned by Pamblam below.

Comment: For the record, .htaccess doesn't affect files on the server. It only effects the requests made to the server. in other words the domain name/url not the filepaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the full absolute path..

```
// Path to the current directory
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
include $path.'/assets/header.php';
require $path.'/assets/adminPanel.php'; //file that will not load
```

If that doesn't work then your path is wrong.